# Hibernate mapping between Postgres array of varchar and a Java/Kotlin collection of enum

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, kotlin, hibernate-mapping

Basically everything is in the title.

I have a column in my DB which is a `varchar[]`.

I really would like to map it to a Java/Kotlin `enum`. We've already got this working to fetch it as a list of `String`s (through `com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types` and `StringArrayType`), but not with a mapping to an enum. Do you know if this is possible?

Since we know how to map a `varchar` to an `enum`, and a `varchar[]` to a collection of `String`, I would be tempted to think that this should possible, but I didn't succeed yet.

Here would be a simple sample of my current configuration:

```
CREATE TABLE test(my_values varchar[]) ;
INSERT INTO test(my_values) values ('{VAL1, VAL2}')
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
data class DbTest(
        @Column(name = "my_values")
        val myValues: List<Values>
)

enum class Values {
       VAL1, VAL2
}
```

I tried this: https://vladmihalcea.com/map-postgresql-enum-array-jpa-entity-property-hibernate/ which looks pretty good but you have to define the enum in the DB and we don't want that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting my solution, I didn't succeed to get a `List<Values>`, although I got an `Array<Values>` which was fine with me.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
@TypeDef(
        name = "values-array",
        typeClass = EnumArrayType::class,
        defaultForType = Array<Values>::class,
        parameters = [
          Parameter(
                  name = EnumArrayType.SQL_ARRAY_TYPE,
                  value = "varchar"
          )
        ]
)
data class DbTest(
        @Type(type = "values-array")
        @Column(name = "my_values", columnDefinition = "varchar[]")
        val myValues: Array<Values>
)

enum class Values {
       VAL1, VAL2
}
```

This is working like a charm and I can map my array to a list and vice versa quite easily, which is ok.

Hoping this will help someone someday ;)

Comment: This is no longer possible with Hibernate >6 since TypeDef has been removed (see answer above)

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer does not work for me, but this working:

```
    TypeDef(
      name = "enums-array",
      typeClass = ListArrayType::class,
      parameters = [Parameter(name = EnumArrayType.SQL_ARRAY_TYPE, value = "varchar")]
    )
```

Comment: This is no longer possible with Hibernate >6 since TypeDef has been removed (see answer above)

Answer (score 0):

If using Hibernate version > 6 this changed and should look like this:

```
@Type(StringArrayType.class)
@Column(
    name = "sensor_names",
    columnDefinition = "text[]"
)
private String[] sensorNames;

@Type(IntArrayType.class)
@Column(
    name = "sensor_values",
    columnDefinition = "integer[]"
)
private int[] sensorValues;

@Type(
    value = EnumArrayType.class,
    parameters = @Parameter(
        name = AbstractArrayType.SQL_ARRAY_TYPE,
        value = "sensor_state"
    )
)
@Column(
    name = "sensor_states",
    columnDefinition = "sensor_state[]"
)
private SensorState[] sensorStates;
```

**Note:** EnumArrayType comes from library [HypersistenceUtils](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils)